# How to get list of sites with module enabled using drush?

Tags: drush

How can I find out, using drush, which sites from my Drupal multisite installation have a particular module/theme enabled?

Answer (score 2):

The drush command for this is:

```
drush @sites pml --type=theme --status=enabled --yes | grep bootstrap
```

That's for the bootstrap theme, for a module it would be something like this

```
drush @sites pml --status=enabled --yes | grep pathauto
```